# Access Google Drive files from a Google Cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-drive-api

I want to create a cloud function in Google Cloud Platform using python to extract some files from a folder stored in a user's Google Drive (Google Workspace). I am having a hard time figuring out how to authenticate, and extract the files from a specific folder of that user from my organization workspace.

I have tried sharing the drive access to a service account with maxed out permissions, but haven't been able to figure out the code to connect and get the data out.

I have not found much resources in python to achieve this. Plus the Drive API documentation doesn't mention how to work around workspace use cases.

Edit:
The creation of credentials.json key file for service accounts has been disabled due to security reasons. So in order to authenticate, we must generate or retrieve the service account credentials in the cloud function's runtime (Not sure if this is possible).

I am just not able to figure out in python for accessing single user's Google Drive and read the files (Eg: user_name@domain.com).

Comment: If service accounts are disabled, you cannot access Google Drive files without jumping through even riskier techniques. There are numerous questions about Google Drive authorization and Workspace authorization on StackOverflow.

Comment: Configure domain wide deligation to the service account and you will be able to do what you want from your function

Comment: The service account usage is enabled, I just cannot create the credentials.json.   So i must obtain the credentials from the cloud function runtime. I am not sure the python code syntax to achieve that

Comment: Assuming the service account is granted the domain wide delegation, how would I in python connect to the drive of a user with user@domain_name.com from my cloud function? @Linda Lawton - DalmTo

Comment: Clarify your problem statement. You mentioned that service account creation is disabled.

Comment: I have edited the original question with clarification

Comment: Cloud function runtime service account is not the same as the service account you create for domain wide delegation and enable though google workspace.    I can try to do a Video on it but im busy right now with other clients.  Not sure when i will have time.

Comment: Perhaps use ADC to by pass the creation of credentials.json

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add your workspace service account key file which has delegation configured to the project.

[image]

I just created a new file and copied the json contents in there.

Weather or not this is a secure way of doing it is another question.

but it works.